# What is the difference between `cd ..`, `cd .`, and `cd ...`? What can they do respectively?

Tags: terminal, cd-command

I'm a beginner to learn system program.

I googled for the uses of `cd ..`, `cd .`, and `cd ...`, but it turns out that what I only know is that `cd ..` means to move back one dir.

I tried them in my terminal on MacOS. Typing `cd ..` works. However, when I typed `cd ...`, it said that

```
zsh: command not found: cd...
```

While typing `cd .`, the path doesn't change.

Plz help me for this question, thanks.

Comment: `.` is the current directory, `..` the parent directory, and there is no `...`

Comment: Instead of `...` you might be looking for `../..` to go (at most) 2 directories up.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen as `..` has a different meaning for `cd`/`pushd` from anywhere else (though [my answer](/a/63088) covers it there), and here we'd need to cover the commonly used `alias 'cd...=cd ../..` and `alias -g ...=../..`.

Comment: On one of my boxes I've made a directory called `...`, so in the parent of that, there actually *is* a `...`, but in general @muru is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directories `.` and `..` are special and reference the current directory and its parent directory respectively.

The command `cd` changes directories.  So `cd .` does nothing special (you go to where you are), etc.

All unix shells require commands and their arguments to separated by whitespace, so `cd...` is not the `cd` command, and doesn't exist.  On some systems, `...` is a shortcut for two directories up, but this is not standard and doesn't work on any current systems I am aware of.  So `cd...` likely will give `command not found` and `cd ...` will likely give `no such file or directory`.

The `cd` command is a shell builtin and documentation for it can be found in your shell's man page.  For example, `man bash` or `man bash-builtins`

Details of how path resolution works (including the use of `.` and `..` and `/` can be found in `man path_resolution` and in the POSIX standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13

Answer (score 0):

In system calls that take file paths as arguments, `.` is a relative path that refers to *here*, and `..` to the *parent directory*. `some/dir/.` is the same as `some/dir`¹, `some/dir/..` is the parent directory of `some/dir`, possibly `some` if `some/dir` is not a symlink.

Traditionally, `.` and `..` were implemented as hard links, `.` to the directory it's in, `..` to its parent, initially by the `mkdir` utility and later by the `mkdir()` system call. Depending on the filesystem, it may or may not still be the case. Those `.` and `..` may or may not be returned by `readdir()` / `getdents()`, but regardless, they are always required to resolve to *here* and the *parent directory* in system calls that take file paths as arguments.

As a consequence, that applies as well to most commands that take file paths as arguments:

- `vi some/dir/../file` edits the `file` file in the parent directory of `some/dir` (not necessarily the same as `some/file`).
- `ls` is short for `ls .` which lists the contents of the current working directory. `ls -ld` short for `ls -ld .` which lists details of the current working directory file.
- `ls -l ..` lists the contents of the parent directory of the  current working directory.

`cd` (and `pushd` in those shells  that have it) is an exception in most  shells though, as `cd` implements its own *logical directory traversal*.

`cd some/dir/..` doesn't do a `chdir("some/dir/..")` (where `chdir()` is the actual system call to change the current working directory), but `chdir("some")` or in some shells `chdir("$PWD/some")` (sometimes, even if `$PWD` is no longer a path to the current working directory). And `cd ..` is not doing `chdir("..")` but something like `chdir(dirname($PWD))`.

That is, `cd` (and `cd` only) treats `..` specially by itself in order to treat symlinks as if they were directories, in order to try and minimise the risk
of surprises to the user. For instance, `cd some/dir; cd ../..` should get you back to where you were initially even if `some/dir` or `some` happens to be a symlink to `/somewhere/entirely/different`.

It's important to bear in mind as it can cause some confusion. `vi some/dir/../file` may edit a different file from `cd some/dir/.. && vi file` for instance.

For `cd` to treat `..` the same as other commands, you need the `-P` option².  And that's why it's often recommended to use `cd -P` in scripts (so a program written in shell works the same as one written in any other language in that  regard).

Now, `...` is not special, so it's treated as any other file.

`mkdir ... && cd ...` will create a directory called `...` (hidden as it starts with a `.`) and `chdir()` into it (as `chdir("...")` or `chdir("$PWD/...")` depending on the shell).

`cd ...` would return an error that `...` doesn't exists if it doesn't like `cd any/other/inexistent/directory`.

`cd...` without whitespace between `cd` and `...` would try to call the `cd...` command, which likely doesn't exist in your environment and return an error accordingly.

Now, to shorten typing, some people create an alias for `cd...` as:

```
alias cd...='cd ../..'  cd....='cd ../../..'
```

So calling `cd...` would `cd` to the parent directory of the parent directory of the current working directory (*logically*, as in it would take two directory components off the tail of `$PWD`, not do a `chdir("../..")` as seen above).

`zsh` also has *global* aliases which are expanded anywhere, not only in command position like regular aliases, so some people have been known to do:

```
alias -g ...=../.. ....=../../..
```

Which means that `cd ...` and `ls ...`  get changed to `cd ../..` or `ls ../..` before being executed. That doesn't apply to `cd .../dir` though. There are [better ways to achieve something similar using custom bindings to the <kbd>.</kbd> key](/a/746089).

---

<sup>¹ though if `some/dir` is a symlink, `some/dir/.`, like `some/dir/` would refer to the directory the symlink points to, a distinction that matters for system calls that apply prior to symlink resolution such as `lstat()`, `lchown()`, `readlink()`, `unlink()` and not after (like `open()`, `chown()`...).</sup>

<sup>² well, `-P` doesn't prevent the `$CDPATH`/`$cdpath` handling nor the special treatment of `-` (or `-1`, `+2`... in zsh), but that's a separate issue.</sup>